# Firebase Service worker failed to register & Service worker evaluation failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am using FCM, to get the device token.
I am using React for frontend.
I need to setup the service worker to make it work.

The code works fine when run in localhost, it registers the service worker without any problem.
But when i use the hosted site, it fails and gives this error

*Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https:// abc.netlify.app/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('https:// abc.netlify.app/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).*

Theres also another problem that i couldn't use env variables directly into the SW file, so bard suggested me to use dotenv-webpack, i have created this file in root.

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new Dotenv()
    ]
};
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js (service worker file)

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.4/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.4/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const messaging = firebase.messaging()
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(self.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js'));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        // self.registration.showNotification(event.notification)
        //  add a condition to redirect to that particular app or just to /app 
        clients.openWindow('https://abc.netlify.app')
    );
});

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
    console.log(
        "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ", payload
    )
    console.log(payload.data)
    const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
        icon: payload.notification.icon
    }

    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions)
})
```

Comment: NOTE - The code works when i provide the values as it is in the firebase config instead of using env variables, but it fails when I use env